# Error: Table posts for model Post was not found in datasource default

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to edit my user's information and the only change I have done is change the id from userID to id in the controller function below, as I had changed this in the database, model and the view..

```
Public function useredit() {
            $this->User->id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
            $this->request->data = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The User has been saved', true));
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The User could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
                }
            } else {
                $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null);
                isset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
            }
        }
```

But now its telling me `Error: Table posts for model Post was not found in datasource default.` 
Here is my model:

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class User extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('Group');
    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

    public function parentNode() {
        if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) {
            $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
        } else {
            $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
        }
        if (!$groupId) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
        }
    }

    public $validate = array(
        'id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
            ),
        ),
        'username' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'), 
                ),
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
            ),
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Your name is required'
            )
        ),
        'surname' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Your surname is required'
            )
        ),
        'address1' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter your first line of address'
            )
        ),
        'address2' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your second line of address'
            )
        ),
        'town' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter your town'
            )
        ),
        'postCode' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your postcode'
            )
        ),
        'dob' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your date of birth'
            )
        ),
        'emailAddress' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your email address'
            )
        ),
        'phoneNumber' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your phone number'
            )
        ),
        'mobileNumber' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your mobile number'
            )
        ),
        'group_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
            ),
        ),
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'className' => 'Post',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

    public function bindNode($user) {
        return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['group_id']);
    }

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
         if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
    }

}
```

I have the posts table from following the tutorials, but I do plan on deleting them as they have nothing to do with my website but does that have something to do with the fact I am receiving this error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you declared a relationship between User and Post at

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Post'
);
```

You can perhaps remove this `$hasMany` relationship at your User model (`user.php`) if you do not require this relationship.

Comment: Can you please explain this a little why this happened. I faced the same error and followed this. Thanks!